# Count days until today moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, momentjs

I have a function that gets the number of days until today. It works however, I am using moment.js to write and format the date from JSON data and I think it is causing a conflict. Is there a way to do the same thing using moment.js?

This is the working JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/XeqPT/

```
// Count days due
function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
  var now = new Date(),
      dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
      days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days

  return Math.round(days);
}
```

How can the same thing be done using moment.js?

---

If interested, here is how I am pulling in the date when it does not work.

```
<span class="due-date" data-bind="textualDate: DueDate"></span>

ko.bindingHandlers.textualDate = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var textContent = moment(valueUnwrapped).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return textContent; });
    }
};
```

Comment: *"I am using moment.js to write and format the date from JSON data and I think it is causing a conflict."* Why do you think that? Calculating the date and outputting it are completely unrelated operations.

Comment: @alex23 There are lots of reasons to use a date library. Date/time math is ugly, and full of edge cases (variable month lengths, timezones, daylight savings, leap years).

Comment: When I put the date into the html manually, it works. When I data-bind it into the html, it does not work.

Comment: That calculation makes me feel a bit twitchy. Not all days have 24 hours, some have 23, others have 25 (and other such weirdness). You have a time-of-day on `now` but not on `dateEnd` (it's at midnight), which will further skew the results. Between the two, I wouldn't be 100% sure that the `Math.round` sorts it out for you...

Comment: *"When I put the date into the html manually, it works. When I data-bind it into the html, it does not work."* Demonstrate that in code/markup in the question (and also in the fiddle -- I don't see any data binding there -- but not *just* there).

Answer (score 45):

If the problem you have is to use *moment.js* to get the duration between two dates, then you can use the [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function like this:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var diffInMs = a.diff(b); // 86400000 milliseconds
var diffInDays = a.diff(b, 'days'); // 1 day
```

Now, I don't know if you have any problem with KnockoutJS, but this should ensure that your computation is done with *moment.js*.

Just for your interest, I made myself a custom binding handler for displaying a moment date  some time ago. The difference with yours is that my observable was already a moment object. So, I've modified it down here to make it work with standard date objects:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.moment = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var formattedValue = moment(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            $(element).text(formattedValue);
        }
    };
```

Edit: I made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9xu/) with the example.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me - see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/sBMTn/5.  It might be helpful if you could show us a fiddle where the problem exists so that we can see what's going on.

Here is the code I added:

```
var viewModel = {
    firstDate: ko.observable("2013-7-1"),
    secondDate: ko.observable("2013-9-1")
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And I updated your markup to make use of the viewmodel:

```
<div id="paging1">
    <ul class="list paging-items">
        <li><!-- item -->
            <h4>Due in <span class="days-due"></span> days</h4>

            <h4><span data-bind="textualDate: firstDate" class="due-date"></span></h4>
        </li><!-- #item -->
        <li><!-- item -->
            <h4>Due in <span class="days-due"></span> days</h4>

            <h4><span data-bind="textualDate: secondDate" class="due-date"></span></h4>
        </li><!-- #item -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that your call to jQuery's `each` method can only act on data that is already in the DOM.  So be sure to put it after you call `ko.applyBindings`

However...

You might want to consider using a computed rather than using jQuery for the 'Due in X days' part of the page.  Here is how you could do that: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/sBMTn/1