# MomentJS change 'a day ago' to '1d'

Tags: javascript, frontend, momentjs

I have a JSON formatted date, say: `2017-08-01T23:28:56.782Z`
I've given it `fromNow()` to display a relative date `a month ago`.

Is there a way to format it to display something like `30d`?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216583/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515757/4131048)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count days until today moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424702/count-days-until-today-moment-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might be a bit out of date since there are 36 days from your target date.

```
var a = moment(); // today
var b = moment("2017-08-01T23:28:56.782Z"); // target date
var diffInDays = a.diff(b, 'days') + 'd'; // 36d;
```

The above code gets your days from the specified target date.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) to customize thresholds for moment relative time. In your case, you can update the `d` property that represents:

> least number of days to be considered a month.

If you want to show `d` instead of days, you can use customize [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) property with the `updateLocale` method.

If you want to remove the suffix (e.g. in / ago) from [`fromNow`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) output, you can simply use `fromNow(true)`.

Here a working sample:

```js
var m = moment('2017-08-01T23:28:56.782Z');
console.log(m.fromNow());

moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 30*12);
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    dd: "%dd",
  }
});

console.log(m.fromNow(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer if you want to do it the Moment.js way.

Comment: Agreed, this would be the way to do it the Moment.js way.

Answer (score 3):

1 . **%d** will print no of digits .
2. **" "** will show Sting Literal . eg : Sec, s , d, y, w .

**OUTPUT :** 1d , 1w , 1y,

```
const TIME_ZONE = -1 * new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

 this.getDateFrom("2018-02-22 14:27:56");

 getDateFrom(givenDate) {
    return moment(givenDate)
      .add(TIME_ZONE, "hours")
      .fromNow(
        updateLocale("en", {
          relativeTime: {
            future: "in %s",
            past: "%s ",
            s: "sec",
            m: "%d m",
            mm: "%d m",
            h: "%d h",
            hh: "%d h",
            d: "%d d",
            dd: "%d d",
            M: "a mth",
            MM: "%d mths",
            y: "y",
            yy: "%d y"
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

### **OTHER WAY** .

**`fromNow(true)`** : true will trim your format (1 week ago) .

```
return moment(givenDate)
      .add(TIME_ZONE, "hours")
      .fromNow(true);
```

**OUTPUT :** a day , 1 week , 1 year,