# Javascript: Date A within x amount of days of date B

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to Javascript and need to produce a simple boolean that determines:

IF "January 01 2018" is within 1-7 days of "January 03 2018" "true","false"

Comment: You can use the moment library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424702/count-days-until-today-moment-js and https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Does within mean only before or before and after?  What if they are the same date (0 days apart)?

Comment: Welcome, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542938/4636715) for computing the difference between two dates. Then apply your conditional logic on the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is (if by within you mean before or after x days):

```
var days = 7; // number of days
var delta = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in milliseconds
var result = Math.abs(new Date("January 03 2018") - new Date("January 01 2018")) < delta; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it. `a` and `b` are both `Date` objects that are being compared. Credit to [Ulysse BN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6320039/ulysse-bn) for shortening the code.

```
function compareDates (a, b, difference) {
    if (difference == undefined) {
        difference = 1000*60*60*24*7; // if difference is not specified set it to 7 days
    }
    return Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime()) < difference; // if the absolute difference is less than specified return true
}
```

Comment: no need for `if` statment: `return Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime()) < difference`